# Is it possible to add title to charts?

Tags: extjs, label, charts, title, extjs4

I want to add a title to a chart, like in the [gauge example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/charts/Gauge.html) or a pie chart. I want to display a title under or on top of the chart. Is this possible? I've been looking and can't find anything about this. if so , any tip to share?
it would be something like this [image: gauge with titles]

***EDIT***: i found there is a property to create **text sprites** for the title or any labels at the **Ex.draw package**.
but i couldnt understand how to use it..

anybdy here have done the same?

Comment: Can you not just give the chart a `title` property? or is this not what ur looking for?

Comment: i tried adding `title : 'my title'` but it didnt work :(  cseems that hart doesnt have a title property

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Ext.chart.Chart is an Ext.draw.Component, you can add sprites as items of it. Try to use this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
   default chart settings here

   ...

   items: [{
      type  : 'text',
      text  : 'Simple Title',
      font  : '14px Arial',
      width : 100,
      height: 30,
      x : 50, //the sprite x position
      y : 10  //the sprite y position
   }]
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot,this helped me a lot, but im wondering if u know of a way to make the x and y dynamic, like anchor for example, so when we change the size of the panel/window they will also move acordinally..do u get me? let me know if i need to explain more

Comment: **Note:** For Ext JS 5, just rename the `items` config property to `sprites`.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a sprite to the cart.surface:

```
var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    ... default chart settings here ...
});
var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
    type: 'text',
    surface: chart.surface,
    text: 'Simple text',
    font: '12px Arial',
    x: 50,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100 
});
sprite.show(true);
chart.surface.add(sprite);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, i tried it, i get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined** on the `chart.surface.add(sprite);`

Comment: Is renderTo of your chart setted before you try to add the sprite?

Comment: no.in fact i dont use render to, i just call my chart in my viewport when i need it

Comment: I'm afraid that is the problem. Can you try it with renderTo setted?

Comment: as far as I can see, yes. Than there is no surface and therefore you can add nothing. But I might be wrong. I didn't build Ext.

Comment: @astrocybernaute let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1406/discussion-between-gerben-limburg-and-astrocybernaute)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not using a sprite since you'll likely want the title centered. Any changes to the container size or your text length won't be automatically handled since the sprite approaches described in other answers here all hardcode the location. Centering with a sprite *can* be done with some effort but I'd consider leveraging the layout system. This way your page contents can *automatically* be positioned nicely when your page resizes.

```
// Use a vbox layout with whatever options you need
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'center'
},
items: [{
    type: 'container',
    html: 'My Title'
},{
    type: 'chart',
    flex: 1,
    // ...etc
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your chart inside a panel with the title you need.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'My Title',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: yourChart
});
```

Comment: not what i meant, not title in the header of the panel i have that, but inside the panel right in the top or under the chart,cause in one panel i could have several charts like in the gauge example i mentionned in my question and i want to put a title for each one

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using [Ext.chart.axis.Gauge](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.axis.Gauge). Inside items put an axis config with a title:

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
   default chart settings here

   ...

   items: [{
                axes: [
                    {
                        position: 'gauge',
                        type: 'Gauge',
                        title: 'Net Pips',
                        maximum: 500,
                        minimum: 0
                    }
                ]
   }]
})
```